# Custom Sort array of strings by another array of strings - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string, sorting

I have an array that is currently sorted alphabetically, and I'm trying to sort it by a manual order of strings.

Current code:

```
list = ["gold","silver","bronze","steel","copper"]

list = list.sort { |a, b| a <=> b }
```

What I'm trying to achieve: (With a blank entry as a separator)

```
list = ["gold","silver","bronze","steel","copper"]

sort_order = ["bronze","silver","gold","","copper","steel"]

list = list.sort_by sort_order
```

Output: bronze | silver | gold | - | copper | steel

Is this possible? Currently stuck with these error messages:

```
comparison of Integer with nil failed
comparison of String with String failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that:

- every element of `list` is in `sort_order`;
- `sort_order` may contain elements that are not in `list`;
- `list` may contain duplicates; and
- `sort_order` contains no duplicates.

If `sort_order` initially contains duplicates the temporary array `sort_order.uniq` can be used in the calculations.

Observe that if, as in the example, `list` contains no duplicates and `sort_order` contains no elements other than those in `list`, sorting `list` by the order of its elements in `sort_order` is trivial, as it merely returns `sort_order`.

The following is more efficient than methods that use `sort` or `sort_by` (`O(n)` versus `O(n*log(n)`) computational complexity.)

```
list = ["gold", "copper", "silver", "copper", "steel", "gold"]
sort_order = ["bronze", "silver", "tin", "gold", "copper", "steel"]

count = list.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
  #=> {"gold"=>2, "copper"=>2, "silver"=>1, "steel"=>1} 
sort_order.flat_map { |e| [e]*count[e] }.reject(&:empty?)
  #=> ["silver", "gold", "gold", "copper", "copper", "steel"]
```

Comment: `sort_order.each_with_index.to_h`?

Comment: To generate the `count` table in one shot.

Comment: But that generates `#=> {"bronze"=>0, "silver"=>1, "gold"=>2, "copper"=>3, "steel"=>4}`. I need `{"gold"=>2, "copper"=>2, "silver"=>1, "steel"=>1}`.

Comment: I think you understand the problem better than I do because the question itself doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to just make a medal class or something, with a numerical rank and a string name, and then just sort by the rank. like so.

```
class Medal
  attr_accessor :name, :rank

  def initialize(name, rank)
    @name = name
    @rank = rank
  end
end

list = [Medal.new("gold", 0), Medal.new("silver", 1), Medal.new("bronze", 2), Medal.new("steel", 4), Medal.new("copper", 3)]

list = list.sort_by &:rank
```

you could take this a big farther if you want and define a map of medal names to ranks to drop the rank from the initialize. You could also just define each medal as a constant if you want, since you'll probably only have a fixed list.

But if you don't want to do that then you could probably also just have a list of the order and sort by the index, like this

```
list = ["gold","silver","bronze","steel","copper"]

sort_order = ["bronze","silver","gold","","copper","steel"]

list = list.sort_by {|m| sort_order.index m}
```